# pg_dump taking tooo long with Large Objects - Aurora PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump

I have Aurora Postgres 11.9 DB which has a lot of Large Objects (OIDs). Size of the DB is around 8 GB. Ran some cleanup (thousands of rows were deleted from the DB) and then taking the pg_dump of the DB. Ran the pg_dump with the following params:

`pg_dump -v -Fc -h <HOST_NAME> -U <USERNAME> -d <DB_NAME> -f FILE_NAME.dump`

It has been more than 2 hours and the pg_dump is stuck on `pg_dump: saving large objects`

Updated a few Postgres params before running the pg_dump

```
work_mem = 1GB
enable_hashagg = 0
enable_hashjoin = 0
enable_parallel_hash = 0
```

Need suggestions on how to make the pg_dump fast.

Did not use the parallel worker like `-j 4` with pg_dump because I don't think it parallelizes the dump of large objects.

Pls suggest on how to make pg_dump faster..

Thanks

Comment: Look at the Postgres log to see what is actually happening.

Comment: What is rhe bottleneck? CPU or IO? You could try the directory format which allows more than one thread (--jobs x) if only one core is at 100%. What is the OS?

Comment: @Steeeve -- The source DB is Aurora Postgres v 11.9.. CPU Utilization around 10-15%.  Read IOPS is also low so not sure why is it taking so much time. The reason why I did not use parallel jobs is because I dont think parallel jobs work for Large Objects

Comment: How many cores do you have? 8?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver -- I have set log_statement = none.. So dont see anything in the DB logs

Comment: The messages you are looking for probably will not involve statements, but resource contention. At any rate this involves AWS, so this will probably come down to hidden 'features' of Aurora. I would update your question to indicate that you are using a forked version of Postgres.

Comment: I did some tests today with a 20 GB database having 2 large tables (5Gb + 2,5 GB) and plenty of smaller ones. pg_dump ran 7 to 11 minutes dependig on target drive.

Comment: @Steeeve -- using r4.xL Instance class with 4 vCPUs and 30 GB memory. Running pg_dump on an EC2 instance in the same VPC

Comment: "a lot" is not very quantitative.  Please use numbers.

Comment: @jjanes -- Ran pg_dump for 3 hours. It still did not finish and finally I had to kill the process

Comment: But what is the number of large objects?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: `select count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata`.  Also, do you know if acl's are being used?  I vaguely recall dump scaling poorly for acl entries.

Comment: @jjanes -- Ran the select query which you gave and it returned 7020509. No idea about acl's. Again - Is there a way to check? Also, I forgot to mention that this DB instance hosts other DB's as well which use Large Objects. But I am running the pg_dump for one DB only